# OpenLayers add features to vectorLayer from GetFeatureInfo query in TypeScript

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geojson, getfeatureinfo, typescript

Stack:

OpenLayers 8.2.0, Typescript 5.3.3, GeoServer 2.22

Goal:

Clicking on a map triggers a GetFeatureInfo request which returns feature info (correctly displayed) and geometries. I would like to display a vectorLayer containing the geometry of the last features returned by the GetFeatureInfo query. It should display any kind of Geometry Type.

Code:

```
// Setting the styles for any kind of Geometry Type
let white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
let blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
let width = 3;

let styles = {
  "Polygon": [
    new Style({
      fill: new Fill({ color: white })
    })
  ],
  "LineString": [
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: white, width: width + 2 })
    }),
    new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: blue, width: width })
    })
  ],
  "Point": [
    new Style({
      image: new Circle({
        radius: width * 2,
        fill: new Fill({ color: blue }),
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: white, width: width / 2 })
      })
    })
  ],
  'GeometryCollection': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'magenta', width: 2 }),
    fill: new Fill({ color: 'magenta' }),
    image: new CircleStyle({
      radius: 10,
      fill: undefined,
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'magenta' }),
    }),
  }),
  'Circle': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 2 }),
    fill: new Fill({ color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)' }),
  }),
};
styles['MultiPolygon'] = styles['Polygon'];
styles['MultiLineString'] = styles['LineString'];
styles['MultiPoint'] = styles['Point'];

// Creating the vectorLayer
const selectedGeom: VectorLayer<VectorSource> = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({wrapX: false}),
  style: (feature) => {
    let geomType: Type | undefined = feature.getGeometry()?.getType();
    return geomType ? styles[geomType] : styles["Point"]
  },
  properties: {name: "selectedGeom"},
})

// Getting the feature info with the attributes and the geometries
async function _getFeatureInfo(e: MapBrowserEvent<UIEvent>) {
  selectedGeom.getSource()?.clear();

  const res = await geodataService.getFeatureInfo(
    // Request params to the geoserver
  );

  const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(res),
  });
  selectedGeom.setSource(vectorSource)

// Other stuff about attributes display but doesn't care here
```

Errors:

I can't figure out how to make it work but I tried a lot of syntax and I met a lot of error messages. The most explicit message is the one below:
`Argument of type 'VectorSource<FeatureLike>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>>'. Type 'FeatureLike' is not assignable to type 'Feature<Geometry>'.ts(2345)`

Happening at the last line: `selectedGeom.setSource(vectorSource)`

Comment: Hi @TomazicM, I updated the code with a cristal clear error:
`Argument of type 'VectorSource<FeatureLike>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>>'.
  Type 'FeatureLike' is not assignable to type 'Feature<Geometry>'.ts(2345)`


Happening at the last line: `selectedGeom.setSource(vectorSource)`

Comment: I also tried with this single line of code:
`selectedGeom.getSource()?.addFeatures(new GeoJSON().readFeatures(res))` but I get the same error...

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to provide clarifications requested in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found out the issue spotted on Github [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/15334).
I'll do a typing workaround (like described in the issue) waiting for a bugfix release.
If there is no better way to do so, I will accept my own anwser hopping that it could help some people later.